# Java language spec: "an invocation of Class" as return type of method in annotation type

Tags: java, language-features

The Java 8 Language Spec says in the discussion of [annotation type elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1) :

> The return type of a method declared in an annotation type must be one
> of the following, or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> ... Class or an invocation of Class (§4.5)

What is meant with "an invocation of Class"? Just something like `Class<Number>` , or more than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly that. The terminology is confusing, rarely used, and I can't seem to find it anywhere in the JSL. It is in [a tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), though:

> To reference the generic `Box` class from within your code, you must
>   perform a generic type invocation, which replaces `T` with some concrete
>   value, such as Integer:
>
> ```
> Box<Integer> integerBox;
> ```
>
> You can think of a generic type invocation as being similar to an
>   ordinary method invocation, but instead of passing an argument to a
>   method, you are passing a type argument — `Integer` in this case — to
>   the `Box` class itself.
>
> **Type Parameter and Type Argument Terminology:**
>   Many developers use the terms "type parameter" and "type argument"
>   interchangeably, but these terms are not the same. When coding, one
>   provides type arguments in order to create a parameterized type.
>   Therefore, the `T` in `Foo<T>` is a type parameter and the String in
>   `Foo<String> f` is a type argument. This lesson observes this definition
>   when using these terms.
>
> Like any other variable declaration, this code does not actually
>   create a new `Box` object. It simply declares that `integerBox` will hold
>   a reference to a "`Box` of `Integer`", which is how `Box<Integer>` is read.
>
> An invocation of a generic type is generally known as a parameterized
>   type.